# Multi-threaded list manipulation

Tags: java, multithreading

Can multiple threads work with values from the same list at the same time?
For example, we have 3 threads and a list of tasks that they have to perform:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
List<Strng> tasks = Arrays.asList("firstTask", "secondTask", "thirdTask", "foiuthTask", "fifthTask");
```

The threads started their work and took the first three tasks, but the second thread completed the task the fastest. Now it needs to take the 4th task to work, if it is not occupied by another thread and etc. Is this implementation possible?
I can't find any information about this.

I tryid to work with parallel Streams, but always got wrong results.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  As always with shared objects, however, proper synchronization must be performed.  There are several ways to accomplish the needed synchronization, some of which depend on the particular kind of `List` you use.

Comment: So it comes down in this case to a few options. You could keep a `LongAdder` which tracks the currently taken indices in that list, rather than manipulating the list. The advantage here is twofold: The list is no longer modified (and thus needs minimal thread safety), and the `LongAdder` is atomic, so only one thread will get each index. Another option is to use a `ReadWriteLock`/`synchronized` on the list access/mutation. A third option yet is to simply divide up the tasks (in the main thread) before you send them to the workers (even workload, but not the fastest completion).

Answer (score 0):

You should submit the tasks to the ExecutorService and it will handle dispatching them to any available threads.

`executor.submit(task)`

You can also use a `BlockingQueue` instead of a list if you want to do this outside of an Executor as this is how the ExecutorService work internally.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass each of those input strings to an instance of a `Runnable` task. Then feed the tasks to an executor service.

Note that a `Runnable` has no result to return. A `Callable` does. Our example task here has no result, so it can be defined as a `Runnable`. However, the convenient `ExecutorService#invokeAll` method takes only `Callable` objects. So we use the `Executors.callable` method to make a `Callable` object of each of our `Runnable` objects.

**Beware:** Output sent to `System.out` across threads does *not* necessarily appear on the console in chronological order. Always **include a timestamp** such as `Instant.now()`. If you care about sequence, study those timestamps. Or else use a different reporting mechanism other than `System.out`.

Be sure to properly shutdown your executor service. See boilerplate code in the Javadoc, in `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` method. I slightly modified that code here. Notice that `ExecutorService#awaitTermination` blocks until all submitted tasks complete.

In future features being previewed now in Java 20, [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main) may bring another way to execute a group of tasks using *structured concurrency*. If curious, see relevant Java JEPs [425](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425) & [428](https://openjdk.org/jeps/428).

```java
package work.basil.example.tsk;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
        List < Future < Object > > futures;
        try
        {
            futures = executorService.invokeAll( this.getTasks() );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
        this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination( executorService );
    }

    private Collection < Callable < Object > > getTasks ( )
    {
        List < String > inputs = List.of( "firstTask" , "secondTask" , "thirdTask" , "foiuthTask" , "fifthTask" );

        List < Callable < Object > > tasks =
                inputs
                        .stream()
                        .map( input -> new StringProcessor( input ) )  // Instantiate a task for each input, a `StringProcessor` implementing `Runnable` interface.
                        .map( Executors :: callable ) // Make `Callable` objects from our `Runnable` objects, to appease the  `ExecutorService#invokeAll` method.
                        .toList();
        return tasks;
    }

    void shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( ExecutorService executorService )
    {
        executorService.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try
        {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
            {
                executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
                { System.err.println( "Executor service did not terminate. " + Instant.now() ); }
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            executorService.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}


class StringProcessor implements Runnable
{
    String input;

    public StringProcessor ( final String input )
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "input = " + input + " processed at " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
input = thirdTask processed at 2022-11-03T20:02:22.543733Z
input = firstTask processed at 2022-11-03T20:02:22.543782Z
input = foiuthTask processed at 2022-11-03T20:02:22.555666Z
input = fifthTask processed at 2022-11-03T20:02:22.555675Z
input = secondTask processed at 2022-11-03T20:02:22.543744Z
```